# Wordpress 4 accesible desde http y https con WP Supercache habilitado

Tags: wordpress, https

Estoy intentando habilitar para una web con Wordpress 4 el acceso a la misma desde http y https, exigencias del cliente. Ya he instalado el certificado y esta funcionando, pero no estoy seguro de como realizar la parte en la que resuelva desde los dos protocolos.

Tengo habilitado en la web el plugin WP Supercache y me gustaría saber si alguien ha tenido que realizar algo similar y como lo ha resuelto.

Os pongo algunas referencias que he encontrado por si voy por buen camino o no:

https://www.docsplace.org/2049/01/wordpress-protocol-relative-urls/
https://managewp.com/wordpress-ssl-settings-and-how-to-resolve-mixed-content-warnings

De momento, lo que necesito es que `http://www.midominio.com` y `https://www.midominio.com` sean navegables. Actualmente lo son pero varias url desde https apuntan a http y el certificado me muestra que partes de la web no son seguras. ¿Cómo lo puedo resolver?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu duda puntual? ¿Podrías explicarnos qué problema tienes? La verdad que leo el texto y no me queda del todo claro. Si es sobre esta oración: "Ya he instalado el certificado y esta funcionando, pero no estoy seguro de como realizar la parte en la que resuelva desde los dos protocolos" entonces te pediría que des más detalles de tu problema en concreto. Si tienes los dos protocolos habilitados (recuerdo, http funciona en el puerto 80 y https en el puerto 443, no tendrían conflictos), ¿qué mensajes de error **en específico** te aparecen? Con ese detalle recién podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Siento no haber explicado con claridad. Lo que necesito es que http://www.midominio.com y https://www.midominio.com sean navegables. Actualmente lo son pero varias url desde https apuntan a http y el certificado me muestra que partes de la web no son seguras. ¿existe algún plugin que cuando se accede por http sirva contenidos con http y si se hace por https los sirva por https ? Gracias Luiggi

Comment: Hola, ¿te valió la explicación? ¿necesitas algo más?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero de todo, tienes que hacer entender a tu cliente que siempre es mejor `https` que `http` y que no tiene sentido de ningun tipo "mantener" ambas.

Lo suyo es usar siempre `https`.

Ahora, ¿porque en Wordpress no se puede hacer? Te lo explico:

`Wordpress` guarda en su `BBDD` las `URL` completas (`http(s)://midominio.com/contacto` por ejemplo), tanto de las páginas como de los post. Esto es, cada vez que Wordpress *pinta* el `HTML` lo que hace es poner las URLs que tenga en la `BBDD`, por ello solo existen dos opciones (siempre teniendo en cuenta que no forcemos ninguna de las dos versiones):

## URLs en la `BBDD` como `https`

- Si entras desde `http` la primera carga te la deberia de hacer correctamente, pero todas las URLs que tendrá la página seran vía `https` por lo que los siguientes saltos te llevaran a la versión segura, ya que e así como está en la `BBDD`
- Si entras desde `https` el comportamiento es el normal de un `Wordpress` con `https`

## URLs en la `BBDD` como `http`

- En este caso, si entramos vía `https` nos va a dar un problema de que `contenido mixto` ya que la URL será `https` pero algunos de los recursos se están sirviendo con `http` y eso es un fallo de seguridad y es más que probable que no se vea correctamente la web. Ademas lo más probable es que saltemos a la versión `http` en cuanto pulsemos algun link.
- Si entras desde `http` el comportamiento es el normal de un `Wordpress` normal.

Como te comento arriba, lo mejor es siempre `https`. ¿Que le ocurre a tu cliente para querer ambas? Puede que sea más un problema de dudas/comprensión que otra cosa.